# Как сделать тоже самое но на java8

Tags: java, list, java-8

Всем привет. Хочу разобраться со streamApi java 8. 
К примеру у меня есть лист юзеров

```
List<User> users = new List
```

Если я, например хочу добавить юзеру lдобавить в аккаунт который уже есть. 
Я перебираю по старинке

```
for (User user1:users){
        if (user.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("vasy")&&(user.getNumber().equalsIgnoreCase("pupkin"))){
            user.setAccounts(account);
        }
    }
```

Как сделать это с помощью streamApi?

Answer (score 7):

Например найти нужного юзара и если он есть что-то пременить:

```
users.stream()
.filter(user -> user.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("vasy") && (user.getNumber().equalsIgnoreCase("pupkin")))
.findFirst()
.ifPresent(user -> /*todo*/);
```

В вашем коде непонятно почему `user1`, а дальше просто `user` и с акаунтом не совсем понятно.

Comment: Огромное спасибо
Я писал от руки и немного запутался, вы правильно подметили, там вместо user1 - user

Comment: @ИгорьДианин вы можете исправить опечатку в вопросе, кнопка "править"

Comment: А в чем будет преимущество или недостатки, если разбить фильтр на два? Предполагаю, что будет незначительная разница по производительности, но в какую сторону?

Comment: @ИгорьДианин, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)